# Pybabel misses tagged messages in html files

Tags: python, flask, python-babel

I am working through Miguel Grinberg's new Flask tutorial and have made it to i18n/l10n. Half this chapter had been a headache.

First, `pybabel extract -F babel.cfg -k _l -o messages.pot` doesn't run. All I get is: `pybabel: error: no input files or directories specified`

Whatever, quick Google search says: `pybabel extract -F babel.cfg -k _l -o messages.pot --input-dir=.` will work. It does.

I see all the files it's supposed to be extracting from in the readout.

```
...
extracting messages from app/routes.py
extracting messages from app/templates/404.html (extensions="jinja2.ext.autoescape,jinja2.ext.with_")
...
```

Alight, on to generating the language catalog. `pybabel init -i messages.pot -d app/translations -l es` runs without error and looks good when I open the file. I start copy/pasting translations when I notice my `messages.po` file is 100 lines shorter than Miguel's.

I looked closer at my version of the file and found that while pybabel may have looked into all of my files, it didn't extract anything from some.

I can only speculate that adding `--input-dir=.` may have changed things but I couldn't get pybabel to run without it and Googling `pybabel extract babel.cfg messages.pot "no input files"` returns 3 results all mentioning making that change.

For anyone familiar with the Mega Tutorial, pybabel isn't extracting anything from my `base.html`, `_post.html`, or `user.html` files.

Answer (score 1):

I think your mistake is in the extraction command. It should be:

```
pybabel extract -F babel.cfg -k _l -o messages.pot .
```

Note the dot after messages.pot. This is the directory from where pybabel needs to start scanning for files. I wasn't even aware of the `--input-dir` option, where did you find that? It's not listed in the pybabel documentation for the [extract command](http://babel.pocoo.org/en/latest/cmdline.html#extract).